# How to display output of auto-starting services in Raspberry Pi OS (Debian 10)

Tags: linux, terminal, raspberry-pi, services, terminal-services

I have a Raspberry Pi 3 running Raspberry Pi OS (Debian 10). I have two console applications, one written in .Net Core 5, and one in Python. When you run them, they display status text on the Terminal as they do their thing. I have made them run automatically on boot up by creating two ".service" files in /etc/systemd/system, and doing a "sudo systemctl enable myapp.service".

Now that all works fine, but the problem is that when the apps run automatically on startup, there is no Terminal window where the user can view the output of these apps, like one gets when running them manually from the Terminal.

I know that the user could do a "systemctl status my.service" which displays the last few lines of output, but I'd need something where the user can view the output of these apps in realtime. Ideally, I'd like two terminal windows to appear when Linux boots up, one for each service, where the user can see the output of these services.

I've been googling around trying to figure this out but still haven't been able to get anything working. I'm quite new to Linux. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `journalctl` to tail the journal entries, e.g.:

```
journalctl -l -f -u your.service
```